# Sharing small pieces of code between libraries

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-management

I have multiple pieces of code used in different libraries like flags, exceptions or other. However, none of the libraries should depend on the others. Is there an alternative to

- copying the small piece of code between libraries (and having to maintain this duplication)
- creating another library which the others would depend on (with very few and totally uncorrelated pieces of code)

Do you face similar problem? and How do you address this?

Examples:

```
class MyFlag(IntFlag):
    TRAIN = 1
    EVAL  = 2
```

```
class MyException(BaseException):
    pass
```

```
class MyType(abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def mandatory_method(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Creating another module and importing it where needed is the only option you have (assuming you want to avoid the first).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion (indeed, I'd like to avoid the first ;-)

Comment: Importing modules was invented precisely to facilitate doing this kind of stuff.